# Generate custom package names for Android apps with Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Let's say I would like to have fours apps with package name **com.demo_uat**, **com.demo_prod**, **com.demo1_prod** and **com.demo1_uat**.
To do this, I'm using Gradle and buildTypes/productFlavors mechanism.

I tried by doing the following :

```
    buildTypes {
        uat.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        uat {
            applicationIdSuffix "_uat"
        }

        prod.initWith(buildTypes.release)
        prod {
            applicationIdSuffix "_prod"
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        demo {
            applicationId "com.demo"
        }

        demo1 {
            applicationId "com.demo1"
        }
    }
```

But by default, Gradle adds an extra "." at the beginning of **_uat** and **_prod** and it will produce this output : **com_demo._uat**, **com_demo._prod**, **com_demo1._uat** and **com.demo1._prod**.

Is it possible to override this behavior ? I would like to keep the underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround.
Here is what I did :

```
android {

    ...

    buildTypes {
        prod.initWith(buildTypes.release)
        prod {
        }

        uat.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        uat {
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        demo {
            applicationId "com.demo"
        }

        demo1 {
            applicationId "com.demo1"
        }
    }
}

task editApplicationId {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.mergedFlavor.applicationId = variant.mergedFlavor.applicationId + "_" + variant.buildType.name
    }
}

assemble.dependsOn(editApplicationId)
```